# Vue hints for a react based project created with plasmo

Tags: vue.js, webstorm, plasmo

I've just installed Plasmo and generated a initial project. It's react-based but I'm getting Vue errors in WebStorm. `npm run dev` works without any problems, but I keep getting the red squigly lines everywhere. I turned the Vue inspection off, but these do not disappear. Tried deleting `.idea`, invalidating cache. Nothing changes.

[image: Image of an error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recreated it with pnpm instead of npm and the new project doesn't have the same problem. So I'm going to go with that, would love to get an answer though